# Responsive layout size on mobile?

Tags: magento-1.9, css, rwd

I am using a responsive custom theme on my site and I would like to have a 2 column layout category page only mobile version. How to set max-width in css?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to edit the CSS @media query declarations, particular for small screen sizes and give each item a width of 50%.

Hope it helps